# Prove that $n = i^2 - j^2 \iff n \neq 2 \mod4$ hints

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to prove that $n = i^2 - j^2 \iff n \neq 2 \mod4$ for all integers n, I'm running into issues getting much traction on this. I know that $n \neq 2 \mod4$ can just be split up into each case but I can't really get anywhere with that. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Factorization of the diference of two squares is definitely relevant. Factorize the expression $i^{2}-j^{2}$, and think about the parity of the different factors.

Comment: Hint : For every integer $x$, we have $x^2\equiv 0\mod 4$ or $x^2\equiv 1\mod 4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$(\Rightarrow)$

Is enough to know that $i^2 \equiv \{0,1\} (\mod 4)$ then $i^2-j^2 \equiv \{-1,0,1\} (\mod 4)$.

$(\Leftarrow)$

Write $n=4k+\{0,1,3\}$ and show that you can always split $n$ as a product of two integer with the same parity (see that $i+j$ and $i-j$ have the same parity).

Comment: I had forgotten about that identity, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

To be a little picky, there is a missing quantifier in the statement to be proved.  It should be:

> For all $n$, *there exist* integers $i$ and $j$ such that $n=i^2-j^2$
>   if and only if $n\not\equiv2$ mod $4$.

We need to prove both directions of the "if and only if."

For the "$\Rightarrow$" direction, we use the fact that squares are congruent to $0$ or $1$ mod $4$.  So if $n\equiv2$ mod $4$, then $i^2\in\{0,1\}$ mod $4$, while $n+j^2\in\{2,3\}$ mod $4$.  Consequently, if there exist integers $i$ and $j$ such that $n=i^2-j^2$, then $n\not\equiv2$ mod $4$.

For the "$\Leftarrow$" direction, we need to note that $n\not\equiv2$ mod $4$ implies $n$ is either odd or a multiple of $4$.  If $n=2m+1$ then $n=(m+1)^2-m^2$.  If $n=4m$ then $n=(2m+1)^2-(2m-1)^2$.  Consequently, if $n\not\equiv2$ mod $4$ then there exist integers $i$ and $j$ such that $n=i^2-j^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for the "$\implies$" direction, you could always take the "brute-force" way:

- $[i\equiv0\pmod4]\wedge[j\equiv0\pmod4]\implies[i^2-j^2\equiv0-0\equiv0\not\equiv2\pmod4]$
- $[i\equiv0\pmod4]\wedge[j\equiv1\pmod4]\implies[i^2-j^2\equiv0-1\equiv3\not\equiv2\pmod4]$
- $[i\equiv0\pmod4]\wedge[j\equiv2\pmod4]\implies[i^2-j^2\equiv0-4\equiv0\not\equiv2\pmod4]$
- $[i\equiv0\pmod4]\wedge[j\equiv3\pmod4]\implies[i^2-j^2\equiv0-9\equiv3\not\equiv2\pmod4]$
- $[i\equiv1\pmod4]\wedge[j\equiv0\pmod4]\implies[i^2-j^2\equiv1-0\equiv1\not\equiv2\pmod4]$
- $[i\equiv1\pmod4]\wedge[j\equiv1\pmod4]\implies[i^2-j^2\equiv1-1\equiv0\not\equiv2\pmod4]$
- $[i\equiv1\pmod4]\wedge[j\equiv2\pmod4]\implies[i^2-j^2\equiv1-4\equiv1\not\equiv2\pmod4]$
- $[i\equiv1\pmod4]\wedge[j\equiv3\pmod4]\implies[i^2-j^2\equiv1-9\equiv0\not\equiv2\pmod4]$
- $[i\equiv2\pmod4]\wedge[j\equiv0\pmod4]\implies[i^2-j^2\equiv4-0\equiv0\not\equiv2\pmod4]$
- $[i\equiv2\pmod4]\wedge[j\equiv1\pmod4]\implies[i^2-j^2\equiv4-1\equiv3\not\equiv2\pmod4]$
- $[i\equiv2\pmod4]\wedge[j\equiv2\pmod4]\implies[i^2-j^2\equiv4-4\equiv0\not\equiv2\pmod4]$
- $[i\equiv2\pmod4]\wedge[j\equiv3\pmod4]\implies[i^2-j^2\equiv4-9\equiv3\not\equiv2\pmod4]$
- $[i\equiv3\pmod4]\wedge[j\equiv0\pmod4]\implies[i^2-j^2\equiv9-0\equiv1\not\equiv2\pmod4]$
- $[i\equiv3\pmod4]\wedge[j\equiv1\pmod4]\implies[i^2-j^2\equiv9-1\equiv0\not\equiv2\pmod4]$
- $[i\equiv3\pmod4]\wedge[j\equiv2\pmod4]\implies[i^2-j^2\equiv9-4\equiv1\not\equiv2\pmod4]$
- $[i\equiv3\pmod4]\wedge[j\equiv3\pmod4]\implies[i^2-j^2\equiv9-9\equiv0\not\equiv2\pmod4]$